# Reliably mounting permanently using SSHFS

Tags: mount, fstab, sshfs

I want to permanently mount a remote directory with SSHFS and I've used fstab to do this--but only to some success. The problem is that any downtime experienced by the remote server ensures that I'll lose the connection.

I have scripts running 24/7 on my ubuntu server that are dependent on the mounted directory, so should I just tell my scripts to manually mount each time they run?

Comment: I would configure your scripts to first check if the directory is mounted, and then if it's not mount it.  However, keep in mind any network-connected storage can disconnect for any number of reasons including temporary hiccups - that's something you'll have to adapt for when you're working with networked storage solutions

Comment: If the remote directory is small, cache it locally, and check to see if the remote directory has been changed. If No, use the cached copy. If Yes, update, then use, the cached copy. If "Not Connected", use the cache. "Reliability" and "Network" isn't a valid hope. Program around it.